# how to connect private github repo in sagemaker

Tags: github, amazon-sagemaker

Does anyone know how to set create the jupyternotebook to connect to the private repo as now it says 'unable to access the repo'?

Answer (score 30):

This is a good question. First, you have to create a [Github Personal access token](https://github.com/settings/tokens). Then follow these steps:

1. In Amazon Sagemaker select **Notebook** > **Git repositories** and than Add **repository**;
2. Choose **Github/Other Git-based repo**, fill SageMaker repository name, Git Repository URL and Git credentials with AWS Secret Manager. Username is your Github username and the Password is your **github personal access token**. Click **Add repository**
3. Now You should create a Notebook instance with your repository. In the **Create notebook instance** page, there is an option called **Git repositories - optional** that you should select the created repository. Now click on Create notebook instance.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, I'm wondering how to commit changes and push the changes as I got permission issues

Comment: @bcosta12 - Can I add the repo to an existing notebook? **EDIT: Never mind, I found it. Go to the notebook instance on sagemaker, stop it, click edit, and then you can add / edit the git repos associated with it (after having created one)**